# xliff and visual studio - possible?

Tags: c#, internationalization

I am searching for a way of using xliff files as language resources in c# projects.
Any experiences on that?

Answer (score 1):

There's new tooling for dealing with xliff files in visual studio available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh848309. It's integrated with .NET projects to build resource files out of xliff files automatically, but only for Windows Store Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the Okapi framework, which was originally [developed in .NET](http://okapi.sourceforge.net/applications.html).

Unfortunately, this project has stopped development in 2009, and is now [using java](http://okapi.opentag.com/).